# Render ALL playlist names via Spotify API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, response, spotify

I am trying to render multiple playlists I have created however I can only get one playlist at a time to show. I'm wondering how I can change my code to render ALL playlists instead of one playlist.

```
  getMyPlaylists(){
    spotifyApi.getUserPlaylists()
      .then((response) => {
         this.setState({
           myPlaylists: {
              playlists: response.items[0].name, //displays first playlist only
           
        }
      });
    })
  }

render() {

    return (
        <div>
        My Playlists:  { this.state.myPlaylists.playlists } 
        </div>
);
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Store the playlists as `response.items` and loop over that in your render function

Comment: Any suggestions on how to write this looping render function?

Answer (score 0):

You should change your getMyPlaylists function with this:

```
  getMyPlaylists(){
    spotifyApi.getUserPlaylists()
      .then((response) => {
         this.setState({
           myPlaylists: {
              playlists: response.items
           
        }
      });
    })
  }
```

and you should loop over items in render like this:

```
{this.state.myPlaylists.playlists.map((playlist) => {
  return (
     <div>
        {playlist.name}
      </div>
   )
 })}
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: this.state.myPlaylists.playlists.map is not a function

Comment: map can be used only on array. In this situation it looks like this.state.myPlaylists.playlists is not array or has not been set yet. You can place something like this: `if (!this.state.myPlaylists.playlists) return 'no data';
if (!Array.isArraythis.state.myPlaylists.playlists)) return 'results are not array'`

Comment: I'm not sure where to put this into my code. Thank you for the help